# Has the user enabled the mobile data?

Tags: android

I want to get the "Use mobile networks" settings value (true or false). There's a way of knowing if wifi is enabled and it can be done like this:

```
WifiManager wm = (WifiManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
int state = wm.getWifiState();
boolean pref = state == WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_ENABLED || state == WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_ENABLING;
```

But how can I do the same check for data?

Comment: I believe [this][1] link goes to the solution of your problem.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8243305/790568

Comment: @CRemons Add your comment as an answer and I'll mark this question answered.

Answer (score 1):

i hope it helps :)

```
ConnectivityManager connect = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

Boolean isConnected = connect.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).isConnected();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
public boolean getMobileDataEnabled() throws Exception {
    ConnectivityManager mcm = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    Class ownerClass = mcm.getClass();
    Method method = ownerClass.getMethod("getMobileDataEnabled");
    return (Boolean)method.invoke(mcm);
}
```

and add the permission to `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Comment: Saw this answer on many places and worked well for me. However, for some reason, starting from API 20 the invoke failed. The suggested permissions addition here solved the problem! thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `getDataState()` from the `TelephonyManager` class?

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)Context.getSystemService (Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
int state = tm.getDataState();
boolean pref = state == TelephonyManager.DATA_CONNECTED;
```

This should check the state of the data connection.

Comment: Tried that just before posting this question. TelephonyManager.DATA_CONNECTED shows if the device is connected to the mobile network, so when not connected is shows DISCONNECTED, even if the user has Mobile data enabled.